# How to access each items attributes in a list returned by groupcollide() in Python?

Tags: python, pygame, collision

```
# Variable containing a list of collided objects.
collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullets, aliens, True, True)

# I want to access on of the collided objects (aliens) attribute (aliens.points)

if collisions:
    for aliens in collisions.values():
        print(aliens)
        # print(collisions.values()) returns: dict_values([[<Alien Sprite(in 0 groups)>]])
        print(aliens.points) # doesnt work
```

Terminal Output Currently:

> [<Alien Sprite(in 0 groups)>]

Terminal Error Output:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'points'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`groupcollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) works like this:

> Every Sprite inside group1 is added to the return dictionary. The value for each item is the list of Sprites in group2 that intersect.

So you can do

```
for bullet in collisions: # each bullet
    for alien in collision[bullet]: # each alien that collides with that bullet
        print(alien.points)
```